# laravel API Issue with GET requests (sanctum && JWT) in live server?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

I'm using sanctum to create API and I've issue with GET requests, when call any end point with GET method that retrieve some data like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum'], function(){

       Route::get('/index', [CardController::class, 'index']);

});
```

**Controller of this end point:**

```
    public function index()
{
    try {
         $authId = auth('sanctum')->id();
         $cards = Card::with('contact.provider')->whereUserId($authId)->get();
        if(!$cards){
            return $this->jsonResponse('', true, 'There are no cards', 404);
        }
        return $this->jsonResponse(CardResource::collection($cards), false, '', 200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

**jsonResponse() method:**

```
function jsonResponse($responseObject,$Err_Flag,$message,$statusCode){
    $responseJson = ['Err_Flag' => $Err_Flag, 'message' => $message, 'data'=>$responseObject ];
    return response()->json($responseJson,$statusCode);
}
```

To access this end point I've to login and pass bearer token in postman Authorization, the data is retrieved successfully from database **like that:**

```
    {
    "Err_Flag": false,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 93,
            "name": "Name",
            "qr_url": "URL",
        },
        {
            "id": 94,
            "name": "Name",
            "qr_url": "URL",
        },

    ]
}
```

when remove an item from this json for example the item with id (93)  by call this end point:

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum'], function(){

      Route::get('/delete/{93}', [CardController::class, 'delete']); //for example i removed 93

});
```

the item with id (93) is removed successfully from database **but the issue is:**

**when call the (index) end point again to show data after removing an item:**

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum'], function(){

       Route::get('/index', [CardController::class, 'index']);
});
```

- it supposed return data without the item of id (93), but it return the old data again?!!and still keep the old data forever without any effect!!? like this:

  ```
        {
    "Err_Flag": false,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 93,
            "name": "Name",
            "qr_url": "URL",
        },
        {
            "id": 94,
            "name": "Name",
            "qr_url": "URL",
        },

    ]
  ```

  }
- when login again and generate new token to the auth user and pass it in this same end point in postman, it return the data without the item of id (93) like this:

  ```
         {
    "Err_Flag": false,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 94,
            "name": "Name",
            "qr_url": "URL",
        },

    ]
  ```

  }

**So i must generate new token to access the new changes in this endpoint with GET method??!!**

when change this end point from GET to POST method like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum'], function(){

       Route::POST('/index', [CardController::class, 'index']);
});
```

- everything work fine, but the issue shows only in GET method in live server??!
- in addition everything work fine in localhost without any issues??!

I supposed the problem in .haccess in public/.hacess in laravel root my configuration like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Handle Authorization Header

    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I supposed the issue in sanctum package itselfe but i used JWT package and still the same problem shows in live server only in GET requests too??

any help please

Comment: can you add the content of your method `jsonResponse()` present (or inherited) in your controller

Comment: Thanks for replay, i updated the implementation of jsonResponse() function after controller

Comment: You have an issue with your server cache. You need to somehow disable the cache for your API calls. wich route file are you using, the default web.php or api.php , you can add something to remove the cache globally there.

Answer (score 0):

In your RouteServiceProvider class in app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php add a cache removal using the middleware cache.headers

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->middleware('cache.headers:private;no_cache;max_age=3600') // added this line
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same issue

Comment: @MahmoudDiab Do you have a caching package added to your project ?

Comment: no I've no caching package, I ever clear all caching (config-routes)

Comment: @MahmoudDiab I suggest that you start heavy debugging with `dd()` on every step and check where is the origin of the incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks i'll try, the problem when i try to change anything in this endpoint (like dd() something), it shows only the old data! i must generate new token to see the new changes in the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

There are two more places to check for this problem:

- your local server opcache settings
- and Postman cache setting https://checkinnuggets.wordpress.com/2019/03/27/postman-sends-a-cache-control-no-cache-which-might-be-a-headache-when-youre-debugging-caching-issues/